# Websocket connection failed when using socket.io

Tags: amazon-web-services, websocket, socket.io

I am using socket.io on both client and server, with the application being served from AWS. I am getting a browser console error:

> websocket.js:54 WebSocket connection to
> 'wss://www.tidee.com/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=websocket' failed:
> doOpen    @   websocket.js:54 open    @   transport.js:44 open    @   socket.js:159

**Client code:**

```
socket = io('https://www.tidee.com', {
    transports: ['websocket', 'polling'],
  });
socket.on('reconnect_attempt', () => {
  socket.io.opts.transports = ['polling', 'websocket'];
});
```

**Server code:**

```
const socketIo = require('socket.io');
...
const socketIoServer = https.createServer(app);
const io = socketIo(socketIoServer, {
    transports: ['websocket', 'polling'],
});
```

In AWS, the security group accepts port 443 and the load balancer listens on 443.

The application works when running locally (status 101) and it uses the `ws://` protocol.

Comment: It seems you are creating a HTTP server, and not an HTTPS server.

Reference: https://nodejs.org/api/https.html#httpscreateserveroptions-requestlistener

Comment: @darrachequesne Tried the https server and still have the same issue.

Comment: How did you solve this issue?

Comment: @abhishekranjan I just added an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If using Elastic Beanstalk (EB) to deploy your application. there iss an Nginx proxy server (in the EB configuration) that is deployed to proxy the requests to your load balancer. Remove the Nginx proxy server and the websockets will work. If you want to keep the Nginx proxy, then you will need to configure this to pass through the websocket request.